# PHP connection to Firebird db

Tags: php, linux, firebird, firebird2.5, interbase

I am new to php.

I am trying to write a simple internal website that looks at a job number entered by the user and returns the customer if it is exists. (Verification if you like).

It works when WAMP is set up on the PC using Windows ODBC driver for firebird . But when a dedicated linux server was set up using php5-interbase - interbase/firebird module for php5 , it doesn't work. No errors, just clears the screen.

Can anyone help as to where it is going wrong. I assume it is the connection, but this is all new to me.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0); 
$jobNumber = $_POST['jobNumber'];

if ($_POST['clear'])
{
    $jobNumber="";
    $message1="";
}
if ($_POST['enquire']) 
{
    $dsn = 'DSN=Ostendo Wyma;Driver={Firebird/InterBase(r) driver};Dbname=//Orcus/C:/Program Files (x86)/Ostendo/Database/Ostendo.fdb;CHARSET=NONE;UID=SYSDBA;' ;
    $dbh = odbc_connect($dsn, '', '') ;
    $sqlstr = "SELECT (CUSTOMER || ' ' || ORDERDESCRIPTION) AS " .'"Result"' . " FROM JOBHEADER WHERE ORDERNUMBER = '" .$jobNumber ."' AND ORDERSTATUS <> 'Closed'" ;
    $sqlstr .= ' UNION ';
    $sqlstr .= "SELECT ITEMDESCRIPTION AS " .'"Result"' . " FROM ASSEMBLYHEADER WHERE ORDERNUMBER = '" .$jobNumber ."' AND ORDERSTATUS <> 'Closed'";
    $sth = odbc_exec($dbh, $sqlstr) ;
    $t = odbc_fetch_row($sth) ;
    $result = odbc_result($sth, 'Result') ;
    $message1 = $jobNumber . " Returns " .$result;
}
?>
<html>
<style>
    body 
    {
        font-family:arial;
        font-size:12;
    }
</style>
<title>Ostendo Test</title>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <body>
        <table border = 3>
            <tr>
                <td> Assembly/Job Number: </td>
                <td> <input type=text name=jobNumber value="<?php echo $jobNumber;?>" size="50" autofocus>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan = 3>
                <input type="submit" name="enquire" value="Validate">
                <input type="submit" name="clear" value="Clear">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
echo "<br><br>";
echo "<font face='arial' size='4'>";
echo $message1;
echo "</font>";
?>   
</body>
</html>
```

I disabled error reporting (i.e. changed 0 to 1) and no change or error messages. I then removed the line altogether, and again no change or error messaging.

I turned on PHP error handling and got the following when refreshing the page:

```
Notice: Undefined index: jobNumber in /var/www/Enquire.php on line 2
Notice: Undefined index: clear in /var/www/Enquire.php on line 4
Notice: Undefined index: enquire in /var/www/Enquire.php on line 9
```

(Then below the boxes/table I got the following error msgs)

```
Notice: Undefined variable: message1 in /var/www/Enquire.php on line 49
```

This makes me thing I have not declared some variables correctly. ?

When I enter a valid job reference I now get the following:

Notice: Undefined index: clear in /var/www/Enquire.php on line 4

Fatal error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect() in /var/www/Enquire.php on line 12

So I guess it has to do with how I am connecting to the FB database.

Comment: Why not use the firebird extension? http://php.net/manual/en/book.ibase.php

Comment: And don't use `<font>` tags. If you're new to this, break that habit *right now*, while it's early.

Comment: If it "just clears the screen" it's like a php fatal error. A great reason to not turn error reporting off at the top of your script.

Comment: Enable error reporting (or don't disable it like you do now), and add the error message to your question.

Comment: I have added the error messages above. I am now trying to replace the ODBC references with ibase and it seems to be working as different errors appear as I change each ODBC reference.